# Concave polygons overlapping test

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

I have set of $N$ concave polygons, given as list of 2D Euclidean coordinates. How to compute:

a. if **any** of them are overlapping?

b. if **one arbitrarily selected polygon** overlaps with any of the remaining $N-1$ polygons?

No need for obtaining points of intersection of the polygon's borders. The second answer **b** is sufficient, but maybe there also exists specialized algorithm for answering **a**.

Comment: Do you consider two polygons that share an edge to be overlapping?

Comment: And, are these integer coordinates or floats? (I'm asking this because it sounds like a programming problem...)

Comment: For b, could you use the algorithm described here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection

Comment: @anorton: floats. Sharing edge could mean no-overlapping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they intersect, either one of the polygons must be fully contained within the other, or their edges must intersect, so it's enough to

- pick a random vertex of either polygon, and see if it lies inside the other polygon
- check if there edge segments intersects.

If one of these tests returns true, then they intersect, otherwise they don't.

This can be implemented efficiently with a simple [sweep line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: In the second step, you mean to check, if there are any edge intersections between polygons? Naive approach would require k*l intersection tests, where k, l are vertex counts of the two polygons. As far as I understand, this can be done quite quick with sweep line algorithm?

Comment: That's correct:). It's also quite possible to integrate the first check into this sweep line algorithm easily, so that it requires only one pass.

Comment: How would you test if a vertex is in a concave polygon though ?

Comment: There's also this pixel perfect case if any edge is on the other's body vertex, that it won't count as an intersection. Example: Square A (0|0, 2|0, 2|2, 0|2) and Square B (3|1, 2|2, 1|1, 2|0). Both square overlap in the triangle C (2|0, 2|2, 1|1), however _technically_ speaking the edge segments don't intersect.